# Mount Btrfs raid 5 from failed ReadyNas 104 on Linux - aka how I restore data from my ReadyNas

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm, btrfs, readynas

After about 7 years my ReadyNas finally failed, I would expect from Neatgear detailed recovery instruction, but I read dozens of threads - my problem is not uncommon, but solution was not found.

After quick research I found 3-4 major players to provide recovery programs for windows - all are quite expensive, as people value their data...

I believe I had the latest NetGear OS 6 at the even when it failed (2-3 weeks back), 4 disk by 4TB each - raid 5.

So, i decided to give a try with Linux... took **Ubuntu 20.04LTS**.

*Installing mdadm and checking btrfs*

```
apt-get update

apt-get install mdadm

modinfo btrfs | grep version
srcversion: ACBD2347FFF0DB004CA4F96
vermagic: 5.15.0-43-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
```

*Assembling raid*

```
mdadm --assemble --scan
mdadm: /dev/md/0 has been started with 4 drives.
mdadm: /dev/md/1 has been started with 4 drives.
mdadm: /dev/md/data-0 has been started with 4 drives.
```

*Checking raid*

```
cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4]
md127 : active raid5 sde3[0] sda3[3] sdb3[4] sdd3[1]
11706500352 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 64k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/4] [UUUU]

md1 : active raid6 sda2[0] sde2[3] sdd2[2] sdb2[1]
1046528 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/4] [UUUU]

md0 : active raid1 sde1[0] sda1[3] sdb1[2] sdd1[1]
4190208 blocks super 1.2 [4/4] [UUUU]
```

*More details*

```
mdadm --detail /dev/md127
/dev/md127:
Version : 1.2
Creation Time : Tue Nov 11 02:45:28 2014
Raid Level : raid5
Array Size : 11706500352 (10.90 TiB 11.99 TB)
Used Dev Size : 3902166784 (3.63 TiB 4.00 TB)
Raid Devices : 4
Total Devices : 4
Persistence : Superblock is persistent

Update Time : Wed Nov 30 02:26:47 2022
State : clean
Active Devices : 4
Working Devices : 4
Failed Devices : 0
Spare Devices : 0

Layout : left-symmetric
Chunk Size : 64K

Consistency Policy : resync

Name : 0e36db36:data-0
UUID : 93bd4b5a:c6d3c47d:cd03b2e6:0f16a169
Events : 37041

Number Major Minor RaidDevice State
0 8 67 0 active sync /dev/sde3
1 8 51 1 active sync /dev/sdd3
4 8 19 2 active sync /dev/sdb3
3 8 3 3 active sync /dev/sda3
```

*Checking btrfs volume*

```
btrfs fi label /dev/md127
0e36db36:data
```

*More checks*

```
btrfs filesystem show
Label: '0e36db36:data' uuid: 40a8107f-5114-4c1c-94d6-54bc71f69a7c
Total devices 1 FS bytes used 10.10TiB
devid 1 size 10.90TiB used 10.27TiB path /dev/md127



Checking logs

dmesg

[ 3115.651958] md: md0 stopped.
[ 3115.661011] md/raid1:md0: active with 4 out of 4 mirrors
[ 3115.661023] md0: detected capacity change from 0 to 8380416
[ 3117.469235] md: md1 stopped.
[ 3117.474369] async_tx: api initialized (async)
[ 3117.499570] md/raid:md1: device sda2 operational as raid disk 0
[ 3117.499574] md/raid:md1: device sde2 operational as raid disk 3
[ 3117.499575] md/raid:md1: device sdd2 operational as raid disk 2
[ 3117.499577] md/raid:md1: device sdb2 operational as raid disk 1
[ 3117.500103] md/raid:md1: raid level 6 active with 4 out of 4 devices, algorithm 2
[ 3117.500120] md1: detected capacity change from 0 to 2093056
[ 3117.648661] md: md127 stopped.
[ 3117.660642] md/raid:md127: device sde3 operational as raid disk 0
[ 3117.660654] md/raid:md127: device sda3 operational as raid disk 3
[ 3117.660660] md/raid:md127: device sdb3 operational as raid disk 2
[ 3117.660665] md/raid:md127: device sdd3 operational as raid disk 1
[ 3117.662671] md/raid:md127: raid level 5 active with 4 out of 4 devices, algorithm 2
[ 3117.662831] md127: detected capacity change from 0 to 23413000704
[ 3117.913560] BTRFS: device label 0e36db36:data devid 1 transid 3643415 /dev/md127 scanned by systemd-udevd (10428)
```

**So, at this point I believe raid is OK,  and I could mount md0 with root of ReadyNas.**

*So, starting btrfs games now.*

*Command I expected to work according to all possible information I found*

```
mount -t btrfs -o ro /dev/md127 /mnt

mount: /mnt: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md127, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.



dmesg

[ 4308.157063] BTRFS info (device md127): flagging fs with big metadata feature
[ 4308.157074] BTRFS info (device md127): disk space caching is enabled
[ 4310.614947] BTRFS critical (device md127): corrupt leaf: root=1 block=28693330493440 slot=49, invalid root flags, have 0x10000 expect mask 0x1000000000001
[ 4310.614970] BTRFS error (device md127): block=28693330493440 read time tree block corruption detected
[ 4310.619823] BTRFS critical (device md127): corrupt leaf: root=1 block=28693330493440 slot=49, invalid root flags, have 0x10000 expect mask 0x1000000000001
[ 4310.619846] BTRFS error (device md127): block=28693330493440 read time tree block corruption detected
[ 4310.619891] BTRFS warning (device md127): failed to read root (objectid=2): -5
[ 4310.634017] BTRFS error (device md127): open_ctree failed
```

*Retrying with recovery*

```
mount -t btrfs -o ro,recovery /dev/md127 /mnt
mount: /mnt: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md127, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.



dmesg

[ 4498.628078] BTRFS info (device md127): flagging fs with big metadata feature
[ 4498.628095] BTRFS warning (device md127): 'recovery' is deprecated, use 'rescue=usebackuproot' instead
[ 4498.628100] BTRFS info (device md127): trying to use backup root at mount time
[ 4498.628104] BTRFS info (device md127): disk space caching is enabled
[ 4498.664705] BTRFS critical (device md127): corrupt leaf: root=1 block=28693330493440 slot=49, invalid root flags, have 0x10000 expect mask 0x1000000000001
[ 4498.664711] BTRFS error (device md127): block=28693330493440 read time tree block corruption detected
[ 4498.664877] BTRFS critical (device md127): corrupt leaf: root=1 block=28693330493440 slot=49, invalid root flags, have 0x10000 expect mask 0x1000000000001
[ 4498.664881] BTRFS error (device md127): block=28693330493440 read time tree block corruption detected
[ 4498.664886] BTRFS warning (device md127): failed to read root (objectid=2): -5
[ 4498.708647] BTRFS critical (device md127): corrupt leaf: root=1 block=28693526478848 slot=49, invalid root flags, have 0x10000 expect mask 0x1000000000001
[ 4498.708657] BTRFS error (device md127): block=28693526478848 read time tree block corruption detected
[ 4498.712357] BTRFS critical (device md127): corrupt leaf: root=1 block=28693526478848 slot=49, invalid root flags, have 0x10000 expect mask 0x1000000000001
[ 4498.712367] BTRFS error (device md127): block=28693526478848 read time tree block corruption detected
[ 4498.712392] BTRFS warning (device md127): failed to read root (objectid=2): -5
[ 4498.731972] BTRFS error (device md127): parent transid verify failed on 28693524611072 wanted 3643412 found 3643414
[ 4498.744606] BTRFS error (device md127): parent transid verify failed on 28693524611072 wanted 3643412 found 3643414
[ 4498.744637] BTRFS warning (device md127): couldn't read tree root
[ 4498.771820] BTRFS error (device md127): parent transid verify failed on 28693524971520 wanted 3643413 found 3643415
[ 4498.781483] BTRFS error (device md127): parent transid verify failed on 28693524971520 wanted 3643413 found 3643415
[ 4498.781513] BTRFS warning (device md127): couldn't read tree root
[ 4498.795150] BTRFS error (device md127): open_ctree failed
```

*Let's check filesystem*

```
btrfs check /dev/md127

pening filesystem to check...
Checking filesystem on /dev/md127
UUID: 40a8107f-5114-4c1c-94d6-54bc71f69a7c
[1/7] checking root items
[2/7] checking extents
[3/7] checking free space cache
[4/7] checking fs roots
[5/7] checking only csums items (without verifying data)
[6/7] checking root refs
[7/7] checking quota groups skipped (not enabled on this FS)
found 11110486872064 bytes used, no error found
total csum bytes: 436299240
total tree bytes: 2136965120
total fs tree bytes: 840761344
total extent tree bytes: 627933184
btree space waste bytes: 434774783
file data blocks allocated: 11185027407872
referenced 11311939104768
```

**So, filesystem seems to be ok, so, I suspect btrfs options/features are different between OS 6 and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS**

*Going deeper into btrfs*

```
btrfs inspect-internal dump-super /dev/md127
superblock: bytenr=65536, device=/dev/md127
---------------------------------------------------------
csum_type 0 (crc32c)
csum_size 4
csum 0xd7757ba3 [match]
bytenr 65536
flags 0x1
( WRITTEN )
magic _BHRfS_M [match]
fsid 40a8107f-5114-4c1c-94d6-54bc71f69a7c
metadata_uuid 40a8107f-5114-4c1c-94d6-54bc71f69a7c
label 0e36db36:data
generation 3643415
root 28693330231296
sys_array_size 129
chunk_root_generation 3641017
root_level 1
chunk_root 28035093004288
chunk_root_level 1
log_root 0
log_root_transid 0
log_root_level 0
total_bytes 11987456360448
bytes_used 11110486872064
sectorsize 4096
nodesize 32768
leafsize (deprecated) 32768
stripesize 4096
root_dir 6
num_devices 1
compat_flags 0x0
compat_ro_flags 0x0
incompat_flags 0x21
( MIXED_BACKREF |
BIG_METADATA )
cache_generation 18446744073709551615
uuid_tree_generation 3643414
dev_item.uuid 45694a58-7723-45b1-be77-2e8bee500448
dev_item.fsid 40a8107f-5114-4c1c-94d6-54bc71f69a7c [match]
dev_item.type 2
dev_item.total_bytes 11987456360448
dev_item.bytes_used 11289397035008
dev_item.io_align 4096
dev_item.io_width 4096
dev_item.sector_size 4096
dev_item.devid 1
dev_item.dev_group 0
dev_item.seek_speed 0
dev_item.bandwidth 0
dev_item.generation 0
```

So, that's where I stuck, I suspect it's something to do with MIXED_BACKREF and BIG_METADATA flags marked as incompartible.

Alternatively, I'm considering downgrading ubuntu to 14 and potentially get lower version of Btrfs.

Comment: What failed exactly? Some physical component?

Comment: ReadyNas switches off 1 second after switching on - seems like electic component, not that worried about the NAS - was looking the way to extract data

Comment: Well, getting a device up and running is often easiest way to get the data. I have similar symptoms with PCs and laptops and it cost me like $30 to get it repaired.

Answer (score 2):

If I only knew it could be as simple - as I spend hours and hours trying to fix it.
I still don't know how to workaround compatibility flags, but downgrading to ubuntu 14.06 LTS did the trick, btrfs got version 4.x and everything just worked.

So, if you are dealing with restoring Btrfs volume from ReadyNas do not go for the most recent version of Btrfs.

P.S. I hope this response will be useful to people as I saw many similar questions and no single answer.